# What causes a filesystem to get corrupted?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ext4, fsck

I just went through the following: When rebooting my Ubuntu PC, I got a message that welcomed me to emergency mode. Following the instructions from another stackoverflow post, I ended up running `fsck.ext4` on my root partition from a live USB. This proposed some fixes which I accepted, and since then things have been looking fine again.

However, I wonder what this whole ordeal means. I'm assuming it's not normal for things to just break, is it? Does this mean anything about my SSD drive possibly getting old and unstable? Is it something else that I can do anything about? Or is this just something that one has to go through from time to time? I haven't done anything to my system that I'm aware of that can trigger this. I install updates using `apt dist-upgrade` and I install new programs via `apt` or `snap` from time to time and that's about it.

Comment: there can be all kinds of causes, including random cosmic rays or the media producing an alpha particle, that happens to impact the value of a critical bit. generally speaking file system corruption is caused by power loss during a write operation, or in a case where there are cached writes that haven't yet been written to disk. FS checking tools like fsck attempt to reconcile inconsistencies between the file system metadata and the actual contents of the disk, and while far from perfect, can help you when FS metadata has become damaged. can't do much for cached or incomplete writes though.

Comment: this article is fascinating: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_error

Comment: Also, FS checkers won't generally help with single-bit errors in files (called Bitrot), but some filesystem features like Copy-on-Write can help. BTRFS has some ability to detect and correct single-bit errors that damage files, but not the filesystem itself. https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/01/bitrot-and-atomic-cows-inside-next-gen-filesystems/

Answer (score 1):

A file system is corrupted when its internal structures are inconsistent. There are essentially two sources that can cause this: hardware and software.

Most likely these days, this is due to a hardware failure. If a sector starts malfunctioning the data it returns can differ from what was written which can corrupt the file system. If your SSD is fairly old, it is probably time to replace it but you can use a tool such as smartctl to monitor its error rate which can indicate eminent failure. SSDs in particular can only be written to so many times per block, so after a few years they will start returning errors. Manufacturers overprovision and save extra blocks to replace ones that got worn out to extend SSD lifespan but eventually those run out too.

It is possible a software error caused a corruption but it is quite rare these days since filesystems have been in use for a long time and so nearly all bugs have been fixed. What it still happen though is a serious crash or loss of power that can result in file-system corruption when the unexpected shutdown occurs while the filesystem is being modified. Some filesystems have journalling to help limit this type of issue but it can still happen.

Answer (score 0):

A few things known to cause corruption to an ext4 partition on the HDD:

- Writing to the HDD [from Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954515/ubuntu17-04-hard-disk-repeatedly-gets-corrupted).
- Running an ext4 filesystem [with journaling disabled](https://serverfault.com/questions/318104/prevent-data-corruption-on-ext4-linux-drive-on-power-loss).
- Some daemon that continues writing to the HDD during shutdown. Though I have read there was such an issue with battery ACPI logging, I have not been able to confirm this -- *If anyone knows of this issue, please comment or edit this answer*.